# How to add specific row into data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a problem with data table in r. I have created a data table (approx. 1x60 columns) by using "sample" function. (eg `column 1 <- sample(data, 1`) and so on. I have sampled over two (yes/no) or five values (a/b/c/d/e). So I ended up with 1 row data table with 60 columns, each column contain 'yes', 'no', and  a/b/c/d or e value. The problem is that I have to have all combinations. I have tried 'expand grid' function, however, I stuck with 1 million rows, so I have to have more control. Is there any possibility to add another empty row to existing data table and fill that row with the remaining possibilities, then add third row and repeat? I mean: if in 1st column there is 'yes' value in the 1st row, there should be 'no' value in the 2nd row and so on. Please let me know if you have any idea what function could I use. I have spend many hours looking for some answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Making a dataframe/data.table bigger one row at a time is not efficient. You say "I have to have all combinations". There are millions of combinations, so you actually don't want all combinations. You should decide how many combinations you want, call it `n`, and then use `sample(data, n, replace = TRUE)` instead of `sample(data, 1)`.  You will probably get some duplicates, so you may want to actually use, say, `sample(data, 2 * n, replace = TRUE)`, then de-duplicate the data and cut it down to the size you decided you want.

Comment: Or, use `expand.grid()` as you did which will generate no duplicates, and only keep the first `n` rows of the result, or randomly sample `n` rows from the result.

Comment: But I don't think we can help you much more than that unless you clarify your question. As-is, you describe a process with millions of combinations, you say you want every combination, and you say you don't want millions of rows.  So you present us with a contradiction.

Comment: Se Gregor said (but with different details): Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). For each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.